# How to format string to a particular pattern

Tags: java, string, string-matching

Let's say I have an input string and I need to format it like this:

```
### ### ############........etc
```

so it has to have first three chars, then a space, then another three chars, space and then the rest. Is there a third-party library or JDK Class that is able to do that?

I was trying to use regular expressions

```
System.out.println(inputString.replaceAll(".{3}", "$0 "));
```

but it's not working because the result is

```
### ### ### ### ### etc.
```

Comment: `String.format("%s %s %s", s.substring(0, 3), s.substring(3, 6), s.substring(6));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
System.out.println(inputString.replaceFirst("(.{3})(.{0,3})", "$1 $2 "));
```

**Explanation:**

Just as `$0` is the entire matched string, so `$1` and `$2` are, respectively, the first and second matched things in brackets.

I modified the `{3}` to `{0,3}` so strings 6 characters or shorter also work (it does however add a trailing space when the string is between 4 and 6 characters, which can be removed with `.trim()` (which could have unwanted other effects) or something more complex).

Hopefully no explanation required for the rest, since it's very similar to your code, but feel free to ask if you're unsure.
[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Example:**

```
System.out.println("12345678901234567890".replaceFirst("(.{3})(.{0,3})", "$1 $2 "));
System.out.println("12".replaceFirst("(.{3})(.{0,3})", "$1 $2 "));
System.out.println("12345".replaceFirst("(.{3})(.{0,3})", "$1 $2 "));
```

prints:

```
123 456 78901234567890
12
123 45
```

Comment: That's cool, but when the input string is shorter than 6 chars, it returns it in format #####. So the comment from @damo is better I think.

Comment: @Behnil See edit, specifically `"I modified the {3} to {0,3}..."`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
String formattedStr = "%s %s %s";
        inputStr = String.format(formattedStr ,inputStr.substring(0,3),inputStr.substring(3,6),inputStr.substring(6) );
```